# Incorrect output with counting

Tags: java, input, output

I was coding on a program that would keep on accepting numbers until the user enters -1. Then it would display the number of items that are divisible by 9; using a special property- sum of digits of numbers that are divisible by 9, are themselves divisible by 9. I have been told to rely on a **heavily modular** approach. Simple input, no arrays.

There is no compilation errors and stuff, but the value of count is always wrong. For instance, if I input **18,18,4,4,2,5,19,36,-1**, the expected output is **3**, but the output comes out as 4. I have no clue why. I have tried count++ and ++count, they yield the same output. Where am I going wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Div{
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); boolean run = true; static int n = 0; 
static int count = 0;
public static void main(String[] args){

    Div a = new Div();
    a.accept();
    a.display();

}
void accept(){
    while (run){
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        if (isDivisibleByNine(n)){
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (n == -1){
            run = false;
        }
    }
 }
 static int sumOfDigits(int a){
    int m = a; int sum = 0;
    while (m>0){
        sum = sum + (m%10); m /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
 }
static boolean isDivisibleByNine(int x){
    if (sumOfDigits(x)%9==0){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
void display(){
    System.out.println("The total number of numbers that are divisible are: " + count);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting the ones that are considered divisible? Then you can see which one is causing the issue and debug from there.

Comment: Try `if(n==-1)` first and then `else if (isDivisibleByNine(n))`

Comment: @CoolGuy, awesome answer! Such a minor difference in coding and such a huge gap in output. Fabulous! Works fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final number that your program believes is divisible by 9 is your -1.

You go through the complete loop for it - your sum only goes while the number is above 0, so it terminates immediately and returns 0. `0 % 9` is 0, so it increments your counter then ends. Check for this by changing your loop:

```
    if (n == -1){
        run = false;
    }
   else if (isDivisibleByNine(n)){
        count = count + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your end value -1. For -1 also your sumOfDigits function will return 0. so only count is incremented by 1 always.

```
while (run){
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    if (n == -1){
        break; //Break if the end of input reached.
    }
    if (isDivisibleByNine(n)){
        count = count + 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not computing the sum of digits.

This is how you compute it :

```
 static int sumOfDigits(int a){
    int m = a; int sum = 0;
    while (m>0){
        sum = sum + (m%10);
        m /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
 }
```

EDIT (after your fix of `sumOfDigits`) :

You get the wrong count because you also check if `-1` is divisible by 9, and it returns true, because `sumOfDigits` doesn't handle negative integers properly.

Here's an easy fix:

```
void accept(){
    while (run){
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        if (n == -1){
            run = false;
        }
        else if (isDivisibleByNine(n)){
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I fixed it, but even with that, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

change as this .

```
static boolean isDivisibleByNine(int x){
if(x>0){
if (sumOfDigits(x)%9==0){
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```